# How to check name array fields using Jquery validation?

Tags: jquery, validation

I would like to create an array from form input fields and using the jQuery Validation Plugin.

Here is my code

```
<form id="submit_form" method="post">
  <input type='text' name='item[]' required><br>  <!-- Jquery validation plugin just check this one-->  
  <input type='text' name='item[]' required> <br>
  <input type='text' name='item[]' required> <br>        
 <input type="submit" text="Submit" >
</form>
```

Validate code:

```
$("#submit_form").validate(
      {
        rules: 
        {
          'item[]':{
            required: true,
          }
         }
      });
```

But it only check the first input field,

in order to remind the users fill in the form,
Is it possible to check all input field whose has `name="item[]"` tag???

Thank you very much
full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/oef8j39y/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<form id="submit_form" method="post">
<input type='text' name='item[]' required><br>    
<input type='text' name='item[]' required> <br>       
<span class="a"></span>   
 <input type="submit" text="Submit" >
</form>
<br><br><br><br>    
     

     
<button id="btn1">Append Input Field</button>
<script>
$(function()
{
   $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $(".a").append("<input type='text' name='item[]'><br> ");
  });
    $("#submit_form").validate(
      {
        rules: 
        {
          'item[]':{
            required: true,
          }
         }
      });   
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```